# Modal Window not overlapping taskbar in Windows 7 on laptop

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a modal window that works on desktops with multiple monitors however when I attempt to run the application on a laptop its not overlapping the task bar. Below is the code I'm using to launch it.

```
if (result != DialogResult.Yes) return;
try
{
    using (var fullscreenForm = new fullscreenkForm(eventDetails))
    {
        fullscreenForm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
finally
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Inside the application I have:

```
WindowState = Maximized
StartPosition = CenterScreen
AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly
FormBorderStyle = None
TopMost = true
```

Any help thoughts or help is well appreciated

Comment: That probably has more to do with your laptop than Winforms.  Older Windows versions had a taskbar option that prevented windows from overlapping it.

Comment: The laptop is using the same version of Windows 7 Enterprise. I'm trying this setting right now.
    Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;